# Finding the rate of an angle (related rates)

Tags: calculus, related-rates

I have this problem:

[Police car problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y04w4.png)

[image]

From this problem, I created my equation, which is:

$\tan \theta$ = $x/y$

Deriving the equation, I got:

$\sec^2 \theta$ * $d \theta / dt$ = $(y*dx/dt-x*dy/dt)/y^2$

After finding the hypotenuse, I inputted everything needed for the derived equation.

$(8.06/4)^2$ * $d \theta / dt$ = $(4*140-7*160)/16$

I then got:

$d \theta / dt$ = -8.62 rad / h

I believe my process is correct, because the derived equation involved fits with the quotient rule, but in the end the assignment says I am wrong. I'm not sure if I answered my own question or if I am missing something within my process.

Comment: You reasoning looks fine to me. I think you calculated $\sec \theta$ incorrectly

Comment: You may have rounded prematurely.  Put everything in terms of $x$ and $y$ (note that $\sec^2\theta = 1 + \tan^2 \theta = 1 + (x/y)^2$) and then evaluate before rounding.

Comment: $\sec \theta \approx 8.06/7$